# how to check the check-box if it's value is exist in a text-area

Tags: javascript, checkbox, textarea

I have some check-box and one text-area, and a collect all the check-boxes value in a text-area and then insert it in database, when I select data from database, I just have data for the text-area not for check-boxes. the things that I want is: the check-boxes which i checked before must be checked when I view them. now how I can check if the value of check-box is exist in text-area then check the box? my code is here?

```
                       <div style="margin-top:50px;">
                            <div style="margin-top:-30px;">
                                <h4>Header Options</h4><br>
                                <table style="width:70%;float:left">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><input type="checkbox" id="h_option1" name="h_option1" value="Company Name"> Company Name </td>
                                            <td><input type="checkbox" id="h_option2" name="h_option2" value="Company Address"> Company Address</td>
                                            <td><input type="checkbox" id="h_option3" name="h_option3" value="Month"> Month</td>
                                            <td> <input type="checkbox" id="h_option4" name="h_option4" value="Name"> Name </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td> <input type="checkbox" id="h_option5" name="h_option5" value="Employee Ref No"> Employee Ref No </td>
                                            <td><input type="checkbox" id="h_option6" name="h_option6" value="Designation"> Designation </td>
                                            <td><input type="checkbox" id="h_option7" name="h_option7" value="Date of joining"> Date of joining </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                <div>
                                    <span>
                                        <textarea readonly="" type="text" id="header_options" name="header_options" rows="5" cols="25">Company Name,Company Address,Month,Employee Ref No,</textarea>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <br>
                            <div align="center">
                                <input type="button" value="Configure" class="detailsbutton" onclick="get_check_value();">
                            </div>
                            <br>
                        </div>
```

the result which i expect is:
[image: the expected result]
but it gives me the following result:
[image: the current result]

NOTE: I separate each value of check-box with a comma inside the text-area.

Comment: Could you provide the code of the function *get_check_value()*? The problem should be here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var options = document.getElementById('header_options').value;
options = options.split(',');
for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++){
//Set "checked" for element where the value is the current value in options array
    if(options[i]) document.querySelectorAll('input[value="'+options[i]+'"][type="checkbox"]')[0].checked = true;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/egy9yeht/)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to create an array of all checkboxes which are present in textarea then you have to check which checkboxes values are present in respective array using id of checkbox. Then just set checked and unchecked depending on result of isExist function

Answer (score 0):

Though you can do it better at server-side code(PHP, JSP or whatever technology you are using), but if you really want to do it at client-side then this is one of ways in plain JavaScript(works in almost all modern browser versions).

Create a function to select checkboxes,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function selectChkbox() {
  var strAllValues = document.getElementById('header_options').value; // Contains all values
  var chkboxArr = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  for(var i=0; i<chkboxArr.length; i++) {
    if(chkboxArr[i].type == 'checkbox') {
       if(strAllValues.indexOf(chkboxArr[i]) != -1) { // check if checkbox value is present in all values
          chkboxArr[i].checked = true;
       }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Call this function when page loads. Like this:

```
<body onload="selectChkbox();">
```

Hope it helps, thanks.